# Client Side MD5 Hash with Time Salt

Tags: time, hash, md5, salt

I want to salt a hashed username and password (submitted via http POST) in JS on the client-side with a higher-order time value (< 1 minute resolution) to avoid sending the username and password hash as a constant value that could be used for a log-in attempt via POST fabrication by an unauthorized user (i.e. a sniffer).

This will impose a short expiry on the usefulness of the passed hash.

If they inspect the JS and see that it uses this time salt, how much easier will it make the job of breaking the MD5 if they know what the salt is?

Stephen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [salt doesn't need to be secret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213380/the-necessity-of-hiding-the-salt-for-a-hash#215165). In that sense, your solution is okay.

MD5 is broken in some applications; this one might be alright, but why not use a hash from the [SHA-2 family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2#SHA-2_family)? For that matter, why not use SSL to provide a confidential channel, and better security?

Comment: You answered my basic question about weakening the use of the hash by making salt knowable.  Does everyone concur?

I probably will employ SHA-2, MD5 was an example.  I'm trying to avoid SSL for reasons I will post in another question.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645161/salt-generation-and-open-source-software/1645190#1645190

Answer (score 2):

The time-based salt will not make MD5 any easier to break. You're still relying on 1) the user having a good password to defeat brute force calculations, and 2) MD5 being a decent hash. That's the basic answer to your question. However, this may not be a good idea anyway. Some comments--

Unless you can ensure the client or server's time are synchronized (or you use Javascript to fake a synchronization), the client would have to send the time it used as salt. The server would have to decide if the time used was close enough to the server's time.

Even if synchronized, you'd probably have to accept hashes plus or minus a minute or so because of latency on the Internet. Another problem is that if I'm sniffing I could immediately reuse this hash as long as I'm still within this time window.

Because of the problems above a better idea is to use a one-time server-assigned salt with the hash since it sounds like you don't want to use SSL. In other words, everytime a login form is sent to the client, the server would generate a random, unique salt string, sending it to the client and keep track that this is an acceptable salt. Then the client uses that as salt with the password. After this is submitted once, the server discards this as an acceptable salt string. No two hashes should ever be the same. The downside of this is you have to keep track of these acceptable salt strings.

Comment: Time is a one-time salt.  When I say high order time, I mean I will blank out the seconds so I only need to ensure the server will get the request within 60 seconds from the form submission.  So I don't really need synchronization.  I will send you another comment.  Thanks for feedback!

Comment: Time is not a one-time salt. It does limit the time in which an attacker can attack, but can be reused over and over within the time window. If I'm sniffing a wifi connection and see someone logs in to your site, I can immediately log in with my computer as well, impersonating them.

Comment: Yes, you do need synchronization. If the server's clock says it is 12:20pm and my client computer clock says it is 12:15pm, I will be unable to login if you're not accepting hashing from at least a 5 minute window.

Answer (score 1):

Their job will become infeasible, since you can't use a rainbow table at all if the hash is salted correctly, and you can't break MD5 in less than a minute, by which time the hash is invalidated anyway.

Comment: That is what I was wondering: will knowing the value of the salt make use of a rainbow table easier.  Pretty soon you will be able to break MD5 < one minute.  I may have to apply this idea with an even higher order time like < 1 hour.  Thx.

Answer (score -2):

you could use code obfuscation to make the salt harder to find