# Rainbow Tables: How to defend against them?

Tags: windows, passwords, rainbowtable, rainbowattack

I recently obtained the l0pht-CD for windows and tried it out on my PC and **It WORKS!!**

> [2600hertz.wordpress.com/2009/12/22/100-windows-xp-vista-7-password-recovery](http://2600hertz.wordpress.com/2009/12/22/100-windows-xp-vista-7-password-recovery/)

- I have also read
  [kestas.kuliukas.com/RainbowTables/](http://kestas.kuliukas.com/RainbowTables/)

I'm designing a "Login-Simulator" that stores pwd-s in a similar manner. The current implementation will be vulnerable to the above attack. Plz could anyone illustrate (in as simple terms as possible), how to strengthen against such a rainbow tables attack.

**MY GOAL : Build "Login-Simulator" to be as secure as possible.** (Read Hacking Competition ;-) )

Thank You.

Comment: You want *to strengthen the rainbow table*? I have to admit that I did not read the URLs you posted - but normaly you strengthen the login process against the use of rainbow tables. Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012724/what-exactly-is-a-rainbow-attack and you protect agains this kind of attacks by using a salt: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)

Comment: I think he's actually trying to strengthen the hash.

Comment: @SLaks, @tanascius: Yes, I think he's actually trying to figure out how to make his login simulator _defend_ against rainbow tables. It's not worded very well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_%28Unix%29#Blowfish-based_scheme), which has been designed by professional cryptographers to do exactly what you're looking for.

In general, you should *never* invent your own encryption / hashing schemes.
Cryptography is extremely complicated, and you should stick to what has been proven to work.

However, the basic answer to your question is to add a random per-user salt, and switch to a slower hash.

Comment: @SLaks. Thanks for bcrypt. Regarding the "salt" i have a doubt. if my password is "test123" and salt is "small-salt" then it can still be easily broken. Right?? the aim is to make the salt "really-long-and-computationally-hard-salt" Am i right??...

Comment: The salt should be a reasonably long array of completely random bytes.

Answer (score 14):

Since a rainbow table is a series of precomputed hash chains for various passwords, it is easily foiled by [adding a **salt** to the passwords](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29). Because hash functions usually remove much of the local correspondence between input and output (that is, a small change in input produces large, seemingly unrelated changes in output), even a small salt will be immensely effective.

Best of all, the salt does not need to be secret for this to be effective; the rainbow table needs to be recomputed for all possible password-salt combinations.

Comment: +1 for getting to the point. He didn't talk about making his own crypto implementation.