# How to implement encrypted Android login authentication?

Tags: java, android, security, authentication

I have a login database, from my Android client I have to pass the password in a secure manner. I want to implement a login screen which is capable of doing encryption.

How to implement the security encryption in my application?

Comment: pass the password to what? Are you logging in to a remote server or are you trying to create a login screen to your application?

Comment: sorry i think missed those let me update it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's still a bit vague what it is you want to accomplish since I don't really get what you mean by "login screen which is capable of doing encryption".

If I understand you correctly though I'm guessing you want to have a login screen in your application that your users need to pass in order to use your application. Kind of like a door into a building, or a fence? Well, I can't tell you exactly how to accomplish it, but perhaps enlighten some issues.

#### First attempt – Plaintext ftw, or is it?

The user enters his or her username and a password, check if the user exists in the database and compare the password against the one in the database.

Simple, but not that secure. In this case you will need to store the passwords in plaintext, meaning someone else (*let's call her evil Eve*) could create another application, read from the database and get the passwords.

#### Mitigation step 1 – Hash

To mitigate this you could [hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) your password (preferably with a salt). To hash a string, take a look at the [MessageDigest](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html) class, there's an example available via the link. Now, using a hash means that you (to quote Wikipedia)

> > convert a large, possibly variable-sized amount of data into a small datum

i.e. you get some data other than what you give the hash function. A hash is a fast, *one-way-function* so you won't get the actual password back once you hashed it. But no problem, store the password's hash in the database, and compare the *hash* of the password when logging in.

This is somewhat better than plaintext, evil Eve might read from the database but it would not be the password she needs to enter in your application to log in. Not to worry for evil Eve, "I'll just get a [Rainbow table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table)" she says, "and compare my rainbow table with the password from your database".

#### Mitigation step 2 – Hashing with a salt

So close... Well, in order to mitigate a [rainbow attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012724/what-exactly-is-a-rainbow-attack) you can use a salt, in other words another value added to the password that will create a different hash. The beauty of hashes are that you only need to add a small amount of additional data to make the hash seem almost randomly different from the hash without the extra bits of data. A simple salt can be the username, store `hash(username + password)` instead of `hash(password)`. Now, since hashes are fast to compute, the salt should be hidden somehow. How you do it is [completely up to you](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=where+to+store+salt), but you should emphazise having it secret.

Evil Eve is pretty mad by now, but she *might* just be able to find your salt, and in that case she just leaves her computer running when she's asleep and when she wakes up she will most likely have a cracked password.

#### Mitigation step 3 – Iterations are your friend

Since hash functions are fast, why not just hash the hash of the password, and since they are fast, why not hash the hash of the hash of the password? Hey, while we are at it, why not do it this way. *How long should the user **have** to wait before being able to login?* If it's okay to wait a second, how many iterations can you complete in that second? Reading some answers in [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3566504/116249) might give some reasons to, the more the merrier. Combine this with the salt mitigation and it should be pretty solid.

Well, evil Eve will have a tough time penetrating your login screen by now, hashed passwords with salts and iterations and all.

#### Other issues

But remember, *your defense is only as strong as your weakest link!* Ask yourself this as well, what am I trying to protect? Will my login screen protect that to? If the villains can't break the door, [they might just go through the hedge](http://media.photobucket.com/image/fence+security/EpicLosers/All%2520Pictures/Fail%2520Pictures/fail-owned-funny-fence-security-fai.jpg)!

You can read more about [security in Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136007.html) and the [Cryptography Architecture](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html) if you want to learn more about security in Java.

Comment: This was an awesome post! thank You.You are exactly right, I am storing the username and password in a database.now password is plaintext in database.as i am a beginner i thought of going for some simple algorithm like Caesar cipher(I know it was used before tons of years).let me start with hash,may i know how to implement it,any tutorials?

Comment: @Adhavan: No need to implement it yourself, you can [compare different hash functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_cryptographic_hash_functions) and then use the MessageDigest class to get a hash. The most common hash functions today are the MD5 algorithm (which have shown vulnerabilities) and the SHA algorithm (available from 128 bits up to 512 bits).