# H2 database password recovery

Tags: passwords, h2, recovery, sa

We have thousands of users using H2 database, and sometimes, somehow, someone forgets the password.

**Is there a way of recovering, at least, the SA user password**?

Of course, i tell them that no one would be happy that this would be possible if the database was stolen...

Anyway, i need to be sure, for all the affected users sake.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible to recover the password of any user, because passwords are not stored in the database file. Instead, [the password, together with a random salt, is hashed](http://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#security_protocols), and only the hash and the salt are stored. The random salt protects against [rainbow attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012724/what-exactly-is-a-rainbow-attack). By the way, in the server mode, the password is not transmitted - only the hash is transmitted. See [the documentation](http://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#security_protocols) for details.

However, if the [database is not encrypted](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#file_encryption), the data can be extracted from a database file.

Comment: Thank you, Thomas. Can you point the way to "extract" the database data? Is it a service that you provide?

Comment: You can open the database file with a text editor. There is also data recovery tool (org.h2.tools.Recover)