# Determine Which Part(s) of WHERE Statement Failed

Tags: php, sql, mysql, conditional-statements, where-clause

Let's say I have a SQL statement like this that checks a user login:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE username='test@example.com', password='abc123', expire_date>=NOW();
```

Is there a way in SQL to determine specifically which WHERE conditions fail, without having to separate each condition into its own query and test individually?

In this specific example it would allow the developer to tell users exactly the reason why their attempt to login failed.

For my purposes I'm using PHP/MySQL.

Comment: The time portion of the expire_date could be less than what is returned in NOW(), causing the query to not return results you expect.

Comment: Thanks, I realize that, the field does store the time even though the name is slightly misleading.

Comment: Are you going to pass the reason for failure to the user? That might make it a little easier for a hacker to gain access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I came up with:

```
SELECT
  IF(mem_username='test@example.com','true','Error: Bad Username') AS mem_username,
  IF(mem_password ='abc123','true','Error: Bad Password') AS mem_password'
FROM MEMBERS
WHERE mem_username='test@example.com' AND mem_password='abc123'
```

This way I can detect in code for error messages and then display them as necessary.

***NOTE:*** To all of you citing security concerns with the example code, thank you for your concern. However, this is not real production code this was simply a simple example to demonstrate the question I had. It is quite obvious that you shouldn't store passwords in clear text, and that you shouldn't give users specifics on why login fails.

Comment: Don't help hackers by letting them know that they've gotten the Username vs. the Password wrong! Also see others' responses about not storing passwords in the clear in your database!!!

Comment: This SQL is really hinky;

first, it's bad planning to repeat a field name as an alias;

second, it will never give you an error message - the WHERE clause will only returns records which make both IF clauses true;

third, the 'bad username' test is kind of bizarre; do you really want to tell someone 'you got the right password but for a different user'??

I suggest

SELECT IF(mem_password_hash='c0e1732fa', true, false)
FROM Members WHERE mem_username='test@example.com'

You already know the username; if it returns true, they passed, false means bad password, NULL means bad username.

Answer (score 6):

Well, one thing you could do is change your query so it only matches on the username.  Then in the code you check the password and the expiration date, returning appropriate errors.

Also, I hope your example query is a simplification; Certainly you should be salting/encrypting/hashing your passwords, and you should include something that limits the number of failed attempts within a certain timeframe, etc...

As far as your actual question (as opposed to the results you are looking for), there isn't a way to get that information from the where clause. The closest you could do would be something like:

```
SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN Password = 'asdf' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsPasswordMatch,
    CASE WHEN Expiration >= NOW() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsActiveAccount
FROM Users
WHERE Username = 'user'
```

Comment: A SQL only solution would be ideal due to our current code structure.

Comment: This is the recommended approach. Fetch the user row based on name (if fail no user) then compare the password hash (if fail bad password) last store the rows id (user id) and whatever else in the session and log them in.

Answer (score 4):

In MySQL you can put boolean expressions in the select-list.  Boolean expressions evaluate to the integer 1 when true, or the integer 0 when false.

```
SELECT password = 'abc123' AS is_authenticated,
       expire_date >= NOW() AS is_not_expired
FROM users
WHERE username='test@example.com';
```

**note:**  If you need to write a query that works on other brands of RDBMS, keep in mind this use of boolean expressions is nonstandard.  Use the `CASE` syntax that other folks have posted.

PS: This is a tangent from your question, but I urge you not to store passwords in plaintext.  Store a hash digest of the salted password.  See [How does password salt help against a rainbow table attack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420843/need-some-help-understanding-password-salt)

Comment: thanks for your concern for my security, this was really just an example query not the real thing! I agree hashes are a must!

Comment: Okay, cool, I thought maybe your query was simplified from the real thing, but I wanted to be sure to mention hashing just in case. :)

Answer (score 1):

No, the where-clause is applied as a block, and various techniques are used so that not all rows have to be scanned. Also, how would you know which row was the one that was desired?

Additionally, you probably don't want to tell the user too much about why a login attempt failed. Saying too much allows for exploits such as account mining and password attacks.

**edit** If you truly do want to display this to your user, then split your logic into different parts:

1. **Validate identity**

   Action: Fetch the corresponding user row from the database

    
   Result:

   - If no such row exist => invalid account
   - If row is returned, continue to step 2.
2. **Validate credential**

   Action: Check the stored credential (password, hash of password or encrypted password) against the supplied password treated in the same way the credential is stored.

   Result:

   - No match => Invalid password / credential
   - Match => Successful login attempt
3. **Login user**
   Action: Add data to session etc.

Comment: In my particular case we do want to tell the user this information. We have taken into account the security risks.

Comment: this (and bill's) are still the best answer. just because your query returns a result doesn't mean you have actually give all that info to the user.

Comment: Right, I agree.  One doesn't have to expose the reason for auth failure.  But the developer may still want to know about repeated failed passwords for a given user account, for instance to establish a lock-out.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to separate the parts of the where clause with 'AND'

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE username='test@example.com'
   And password='abc123'
   And expire_date>=NOW();
```