# Salt and passwords

Tags: php, passwords, salt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords)

**WARNING** Don't use MD5 for passwords, use an alternative like bcrypt

---

For my passwords should I use salt like this (the salt will be unique to each user and not stored directly with the password)...

```
$salt = sha1(md5("coders gonna code"));
$password = md5($salt.$password);
```

or would it be okay if I just used:

```
$password = md5($password);
```

because if I used salt, even if the user makes up a bad password like password it won't matter because the salt (in this case) would be `145ac26ff093c6e1317f7d5fb4c9fd11c77be975` so the entry for there password would be `145ac26ff093c6e1317f7d5fb4c9fd11c77be975password` which according to `http://howsecureismypassword.net/` it would take 3 octodecillion years to crack.... so opinions? Or should I be even worse and go

```
$password = md5($salt.$password.md5($salt));
```

If the person has gone far enough to get the salt hash, would anything be able to stop then going futher? < More of a statement this last password

---

To everyone who said I should do it per user... I know, this is just an example.

Comment: Sorry forgot to edit -.-

Comment: You could use `PBKDF2` instead of _salting_ your passwords.

Comment: Read this http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/speed-hashing.html

Comment: Never, ever ever, ever EVER ever (**EVER!**) use `md5` as your password hashing algorithm. SHA1 isn't much better. [Use `bcrypt`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/265575) or, as Florent suggested, `PBKDF2`. Why? *"Its slowness and multiple rounds ensures that an attacker must deploy massive funds and hardware to be able to crack your passwords"*.

Comment: http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should change the salt so that it is specific to each user, not a system wide constant. This will make rainbow table attacks against your password hashes much more inconvenient.

There is a good write up on the evolution of salting in this [article](http://www.troyhunt.com/2012/06/our-password-hashing-has-no-clothes.html) by Troy Hunt.

**Edit**

`$salt` something unique to each password record, which adds much entropy to it. This is usually a random sequence of bytes, stored with the user account.

Hashing is traditionally done on the concatenation of `salt` + `password`.

```
$passwordHash = hash($salt.$password);
```

As others have said, don't use MD5 for hashing. It is broken.

Applying additional proprietary algorithms to password or salt prior to hashing is [not recommended](http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#ineffective). Instead, look at an industry strength solution such as [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2), which, in addition to salting, also requires many (typically > 10k) repeated iterations which will further slow down an attacker.

If you adopt [OWASP guidelines](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet), the number of hashes performed should be increased regularly (to counteract Moore's Law). The number of hashes should also be persisted per user, meaning you will need to store the triple of hashed password, salt, and number of iterations.

Comment: Check edit. Thanks, but I know this. :)

Comment: I think this answers the question the best, because to me it seems that the OP don't clearly know why should he use salt with his passwords. 
If you use fixed salt, it doesn't matter if it would take 3 billion years, to crack the password by brute force, because the attacker will just look at your database table, see that there are 3000 password with the same hash value and guess that it mus be 'password' or '12345' or whatever. You use dynamic hashes so the hashed and slated password couldn't be guessed by statistical means.

Answer (score 13):

You are using the salt totally incorrectly. Salts should be unpredictable; your salt is the exact opposite of that (fixed). Since a fixed hash is of absolutely no benefit, it also seems that you are counting on the salt not being known by the attacker. This is the definition of security through obscurity, which is another bad practice.

What you should be doing is:

1. Use an unpredictable string of reasonable length as the salt. Randomly generated 8-character strings from a pool such as lower/upper case letters and digits are fine.
2. Use a different salt for each user, and change it every time they change their password.
3. Move from MD5 (which is considered broken) to another hash function better suited to this application. SHA-1 is better because it's not considered broken; `bcrypt` is the best because it has a configurable load factor.

Comment: Check edit. Thanks, but I know this. :)

Comment: @SmartLemon: Please edit or remove the first lines of your question appropriately. A minor edit is not enough to let us know what you are doing exactly.

Comment: Like that? I think its okay now

Comment: @SmartLemon: Eh, no it's not OK. The first lines of code still show that you are using a fixed salt.

Comment: SHA-1 isn't considered broken because it's not a key derivation function in the first place. PKBDF2-SHA might be what you meant..

Answer (score 9):

1. Don't use `MD5` as your hashing algorithm, use something more secure such as `SHA256` or even `bcrypt`.
2. Definately salt the password, if someone did gain entry to your database they would not be able to reverse the passwords for common hashes or using techniques such as rainbow attacks.

http://michaelwright.me/php-password-storage

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt

Comment: Everyone think this is correct? I think so?

Comment: Sha256 is not very secure still tbh, here is also a working version of bcrypt done right with a byte range salt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php

Answer (score 4):

First of all you should never store md5 directly, which you regognized already.
PHP 5.5 will bring new methods to easily create and verify passwords in 1 line, until then you can use https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat (forward-compatible) to generate & verify safe password hashes.

Answer (score 3):

I think salt is understood here incorrectly. The idea of salt is that it should be unique per hash. The reason is that when you create hash some different strings may have the same hash.

In your example you're hashing password too so it won't look like: `145ac26ff093c6e1317f7d5fb4c9fd11c77be975password`

P.S. Use bcrypt. It's much more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Salts are meant to be completely random, and unrelated to the actual password you are storing a hash of.

What you should really do is generate a completely random salt, then do

```
$password = md5($salt.$password);
```

and store the user's username, salt and hashed password.

Comment: Don't suggest MD5, it's insecure.

Comment: Check edit. Thanks, but I know this. :)

Comment: @Yogesh Suthar http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#section_1