# How is it possible to compare hash values without referencing salt or saltRound?

Tags: cryptography, bcrypt

My question is about hashing procedure.

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const saltRounds = 10;
var password = "Fkdj^45ci@Jad";  // Original Password
var password2 = "djlfhjd(456"; // Wrong Password
bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
    bcrypt.compare(password2, hash, function(err, result) {
        ...
    });
});
```

This is a code snippet for hashing with salt and comparing.
I can't understand how it is possible to compare hash and password without knowing salt. bcrypt is using Blowfish now, but how is it possible for a having algorithm to compare a password and a hash value without knowing salt?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't. The output of `bcrypt.hash` includes that information. For example, when I run your code, the value of `hash` is:

```
$2b$10$ytoRP21isLcU43jpdiDi4ebR5aKfydE.cHt6VkoH3suODa64JUvEy
```

This is the "2b" format, with a cost of 10, a salt of `ytoRP21isLcU43jpdiDi4e` (first 22 characters) and a hash of `bR5aKfydE.cHt6VkoH3suODa64JUvEy` (last 31 characters). The salt and hash are "radix-64 encoded," which is similar to Base64 encoding, but uses a different table.

When you pass this to `.compare`, it uses the same cost and salt. This is why you need a special `.compare` method rather than just computing the hash on both inputs and comparing the outputs.

Comment: It seems that the position and the length of salt are fixed in the hash. Then what makes this hash more unpredictable as long as we can tell salt from hash?

Comment: What do you mean by "more unpredictable" here? For a given input, hashes are completely predictable. The unpredictability of the output comes from the salt (which is part of the input) being random.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I want to know is if we add salt, what benefit we get.

Comment: You avoid rainbow tables. If there is no salt, I can just hash a bunch of well-known and likely passwords into a big database, and then I can quickly look up if you have a well-known password. If every user has a different salt (because they're random), then the thing hashed will be unique, even if the password is common. So my database won't work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420843/how-does-password-salt-help-against-a-rainbow-table-attack