# Requesting data from database for every single page

Tags: database, web

I am currently working on "remember me" function for login system.

I will store the user's ip, browser, session id and token in database once the user has successfully logged in. If i do stored them in database, i will need to requesting them from database and authenticate them for every single page.

The main question is, if i request them for every single page, does it will slow down my site?

Comment: Yes, the short answer, it will slow down. If you need any more detailed answer, I think you should give details of language/platform in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authentication of user for every page request definitely slowdown the performance of the system.

best way of user authentication in php [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179520/whats-the-best-way-to-do-user-authentication-in-php)