# preventing from users opening other pages without login

Tags: php, security

I am very new to php (started learning it 4 days ago) and I got many questions...

I hav a login page named index.php and after the login/verfication of username process, the user is taken to chat.php which has a link to some other php page called someOtherPage.php... My question is, how to prevent users from directly going to someOtherPage.php without logging in by typing this in the url like  " www.nameOfMyWebsite.com/someOtherPage.php/ "

And after this question is answered, I wish to ask few more on php... Is it valid to ask a slightly unrelated question(with respect to the title) in the same thread?

Comment: "And after this question is answered, I wish to ask few more on php... Is it valid to ask a slightly unrelated question(with respect to the title) in the same thread?"
As far as I know it is usually 1 question per thread. 
Only if they are related to each other they are asked in one thread

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142101/php-authentication-script
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179520/whats-the-best-way-to-do-user-authentication-in-php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to maintain a session for when users are logged in. At the point of login, set a session variable with their username or user ID. Then on the protected page, check if this session variable is present, before allowing them to view the page.

A basic example:

On successful login:

```
$_SESSION['userId'] = x;
```

On requesting the protected page:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['userId']))
{
    // not logged in
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit();
}
```

More info about [PHP Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php).

Comment: so i need to add session_start() function and the isset('userId') function to all of my pages to restrict access to them... That solves it.. I did not think of that..

Comment: @BLOB yes. Consider accepting this answer if it solved your problem. If you have other questions, ask a new question to keep them separate.

Comment: and by the way... a simple list of security tips for a newbie like me would be useful..

Comment: Have a search for PHP Session Security, and have a look at the link I gave, there's lots of useful security info.

Comment: doing it now... Thanx MrCode

Answer (score 1):

Most of  the time sesssion variables are used to acomplish what you want to do.
The session itself is initiated with session_start() at the beginning of each page.

The loginpage then sets a session variable after a successfull login:
$_SESSION['userId']=$userId; //whatever the id is.

And the 2nd page uses an if to see if the session variable is set.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['userId']))
{
     .......//here is your page text
}
else
{
     echo 'Sorry please login first before visiting this page!'; //also a redirect can be made here instead.
}
```

And if you have a logout page you use session_destroy() there (after also using session_start() at the beginning of the page).

Answer (score 1):

Put it into top of your every page

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['xxx']))
{
   header('Location:index.php');
}
else
{
   header('Location:home.php');
}
//xxx indicate your session name which you had set after login
```