# Why does BCrypt.net GenerateSalt(31) return straight away?

Tags: c#, salt, bcrypt, bcrypt.net

I stumbled across BCrypt.net after reading [Jeff Atwood's post about storing passwords](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000953.html) which led me to Thomas Ptacek's recommendation to [use BCrypt](http://chargen.matasano.com/chargen/2007/9/7/enough-with-the-rainbow-tables-what-you-need-to-know-about-s.html) to store passwords. Which finally led me to [this C# implementation of BCrypt](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/10/bcrypt-dotnet-strong-password-hashing-for-dotnet-and-mono.ashx)

In the comments on the last link above someone asked "Why do GenerateSalt(30) take for ever, but GenerateSalt(31) seems to take no time at all?"

I ran BCrypt.HashPassword(password, BCrypt.GenerateSalt(31)) and got my result in 0 milliseconds.

I've been running BCrypt.HashPassword("password", BCrypt.GenerateSalt(30)) for over 5 minutes now and still do not have a result.

I realize we'll probably not need a randomly generated 30 character salt to create our password hashes (or [irreversible encryption in BCrypt's case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561174/sha512-vs-blowfish-and-bcrypt#answer-1561245)) for years. **EDIT** I should have read the code a bit, logRounds doesn't have anything to do with the salt length. Thanks Aaronaught.

So, why does GenerateSalt(31) return a value almost instantly (when it should take about twice as long as GenerateSalt(30)?

**UPDATE**

here is the fix:

```
private byte[] CryptRaw(byte[] password, byte[] salt, int logRounds) {
    // ... snip ...
    uint rounds = 1U << logRounds;
    // ... snip
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I suspect that the bug is here:

```
private byte[] CryptRaw(byte[] password, byte[] salt, int logRounds) {
    // ... snip ...
    int rounds = 1 << logRounds;
    // ... snip
}
```

When you specify 31 for the `logRounds`, it computes that as 2^32, which can't fit in an `int` and overflows, so the hash is actually done in... er, zero passes.  The author should have used `uint` instead.  Easy to fix!

---

Also wanted to comment on this:

> I realize we'll probably not need a randomly generated 30 characters salt to create our password hashes...

Note that the `logRounds` parameter does not refer to the number of characters/bytes in the salt, which is always 16.  It refers to the logarithmic base of the number of passes that the hash will take to compute; in other words it's a way to make bcrypt scale with Moore's Law, making the function several orders of magnitude more expensive to compute if computers ever get fast enough to crack existing hashes.

Comment: See, if they tested `rounds` (at this point -2^31) using `rounds != 0` instead of `rounds > 0`, then it would still have worked correctly! :-P

Comment: @Chris: Lesson learned, always write your `for` loops with `!=` in case of overflow! :P  This is exactly why it's so dangerous for people to roll their own crypto functions; even the experts get it wrong!  I guess this bug just never got reported because nobody has ever actually tried 31 log-rounds before...

Comment: @David: Yep, that will do it.

Comment: I've posted a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223106/jbcrypt-0-3-c-port-bcrypt-net

Comment: Does the fix result in the same hash being generated when using rounds < 31? I'd like to implement the fix, but don't want to have to make all users change their passwords. Given the nature of the bug, I suspect the answer is "yes".

Comment: @KeithS: What fix? If you use a uint instead then no, you'd get different results for rounds = 30 and rounds = 31.

Comment: No, I mean if you change this line to use uints, will any arbitrary number of rounds < 31 produce the same hash for a given input/salt as it did before the fix?

Comment: @KeithS: Why wouldn't it? A value in a `uint` variable is the same as a value in an `int` variable, the only difference is the range. Better yet, just test it on your machine, it should take 30 seconds.

Answer (score 10):

If hashing with `GenerateSalt(31)` returns almost instantly, that's a bug. You should report that upstream (I have, for jBCrypt). :-)

By default, the log-rounds is 10. This means that (if I remember correctly), 1024 rounds is used. Each time you increment the log-rounds, the number of rounds is doubled.

At 30 log-rounds, you're doing 1073741824 rounds. That rightfully takes a long time. At 31 log-rounds, 2147483648 rounds should be being done, but I suspect that the particular implementation you're using overflows instead. :-(

Comment: this seems like a very likely explanation to me... I'll +1 even though I don't know for sure :)

Comment: makes sense: if you double every time and it fails at 31, there's probably a 32bit integer involved (minus one bit for sign ) somewhere that should be using a long or decimal instead.