# jBCrypt 0.3 C# Port (BCrypt.net)

Tags: c#, bcrypt, bcrypt.net, jbcrypt

After looking into a bug in the original jBCrypt v0.1 C# port: [BCrypt.net](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/10/bcrypt-dotnet-strong-password-hashing-for-dotnet-and-mono.ashx) ([Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222383/why-does-bcrypt-net-generatesalt31-return-straight-away)). I decided to compare the new jBCrypt code against the old C# port to look for discrepancies and potential issues like the related question's bug.

Here is what I've found:

```
// original java (jBCrypt v0.3):
private static int streamtoword(byte data[], int offp[]) {
        int i;
        int word = 0;
        int off = offp[0];

        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            word = (word << 8) | (data[off] & 0xff);
            off = (off + 1) % data.length;
        }

        offp[0] = off;
        return word;
}


// port to C# :
private static uint StreamToWord(byte[] data, ref int offset)
{

    uint word = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        // note the difference with the omission of "& 0xff"
        word = (word << 8) | data[offset];
        offset = (offset + 1) % data.Length;
    }

    return word;
}
```

if the prior is incorrect would the following fix it?

```
private static uint StreamToWord(byte[] data, ref int[] offsetp)
{

    uint word = 0;
    int offset = offsetp[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        word = (word << 8) | (uint)(data[offset] & 0xff);
        offset = (offset + 1) % data.Length;
    }

    offsetp[0] = offset;

    return word;
}
```

Comment: Incidentally, the "31 log-rounds integer overflow" bug also exists in jBCrypt (thanks to your post, I filed a bug report with jBCrypt's maintainer). So, doing a comparison between the two wouldn't have located that issue. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `& 0xff` is required in the Java version because in Java, bytes are signed. (Some argue that this is a bug.)

In C#, [bytes are unsigned](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693.aspx), so the `& 0xff` is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks. :o) You wouldn't happen to know what was updated to fix this security issue (http://www.mindrot.org/files/jBCrypt/internat.adv), would you? I'd like to up the C# ported version.

Comment: Yes, it was fixed to use UTF-8 instead of US-ASCII to convert the chars in the passphrase to bytes. In Java, if a character can't be encoded, it is replaced with ?, rather than throwing an exception.

Comment: @David: Thankfully it seems BCrypt.NET already does the Right Thing in that department, so you have no worries. :-D

Comment: muchos gracias, sir. I can now sleep soundly. :o)