# What is the correct format for a blowfish salt using PHP's crypt?

Tags: php, hash, salt, blowfish, crypt

I have read the information provided on the [PHP Manual Entry for `crypt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php), but I find myself still unsure of the format for a salt to trigger the Blowfish algorithm.

According manual entry, I should use '$2$' or '$2a$' as the start of a 16 character string.  However, in the example given later, they use a much longer string: '`$2a$07$usesomesillystringforsalt$`', which indicates to me that whatever string I provide will be sliced and diced to fit the model.

The problem I am encountering is actually triggering the Blowfish algo vs `STD_DES`.  Example:

```
$foo = 'foo';
$salt = '$2a$' . hash('whirlpool', $foo); // 128 characters, will be truncated
$hash = crypt($foo, $salt); 
// $hash = $26HdMTpoODt6
```

That hash is obviously not whirlpool, and is in fact `STD_DES` with only the first two characters of the salt being used for the salt.  However, in the PHP Manual's example, their salt starts with '`$2a$07$`', so if I add those three characters to the same code I get the following:

```
$foo = 'foo';
$salt = '$2a$' . hash('whirlpool', $foo); // 128 characters, will be truncated
$hash = crypt($foo, $salt); 
// $hash = $2a$07$b1b2ee48991281a439da2OHi1vZF8Z2zIA.8njYZKR.9iBehxLoIC
```

I've noticed I can provide some variance in the characters which are here shown as '`07$`', for example `04$` and `15$` both work, but `01$` through `03$` don't work (generates a blank string), and values such as `99$` and `85$` cause it to revert to `STD_DES` again.

### The Question:

What is the significance of those three characters following the '`$2a$`' string which, as I am lead to believe by the manual, instruct the crypt function to use the blowfish method.

According to the manual, '`$2a$`' should be enough to instruct `crypt()` to use the blowfish method; what, then, is the significance of the following three characters?  What then, is the correct format for a salt, if these three characters are so significant?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The number following the `2a` specifies the log2 of the number of rounds to perform. For example, 10 means do 1024 rounds. Usually, 10 is normal. Don't use numbers that are too big, or your password will take forever to verify.

See [Why does BCrypt.net GenerateSalt(31) return straight away?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222383/why-does-bcrypt-net-generatesalt31-return-straight-away) for something related. :-)

Comment: Ah, perfect!  This makes sense, and I guess numbers like 01-03 are just too small to be considered, while numbers like 99 are too large to be considered.  Thanks for the speedy response!

Comment: From manual: The two digit cost parameter is the base-2 logarithm of the iteration count for the underlying Blowfish-based hashing algorithmeter and must be in range **04-31**, values outside this range will cause crypt() to fail.