# What is the refers to 07$ when we use CRYPT_BLOWFISH in PHP?

Tags: php, salt, blowfish

```
crypt('foo','$2a$07$.blablabla')
```

`$2a$` refers to using `CRYPT_BLOWFISH` but what does `07$` refer to?

Comment: I believe this has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/2225675/1089331

Comment: I have actually got the answer this question and thanks Barmar

Answer (score 0):

The number after `$2a$` is the *cost*, which is the number of rounds of encryption to perform. Increasing this makes it harder to crack the encryption, but it also slows down encryption.