# Convert asp.net app to use asp.net forms authentication - password hashing in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, forms, sql-server-2005, hash, passwords

Scenario:

- An old ASP.NET 2.0 application that uses SQL Server 2005.
- Passwords are stored in the database in plain text
- We want to upgrade the app to use forms authentication
- Need to recreate all the passwords just like forms authentication would

Question:

- How do we generate hashed passwords (with salts) using T-SQL for storage in the database that would be identical to the ones that forms authentication would generate:

So how do create this:

DHSicgbY+Av0LyQpBZl2M5EuyOk=

which is a hashed password (plus salt), but using T-SQL instead?

Comment: You can start from this example: [T-SQL: Salted Passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985708/t-sql-salted-passwords)

Answer (score 0):

Under SQL Server 2005, use [HASHBYTES()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms174415%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) preferably using the SHA1 hash algorithm. (SQL Server 2012 now supports SHA-256 and SHA-512)

You can use `NEWID()` to generate random GUIDs for your salts.

> Returns the MD2, MD4, MD5, SHA, or SHA1 hash of its input.

As @von v. pointed out: [T-SQL: Salted Passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985708/t-sql-salted-passwords)