# How to create tables with password fields in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Should I create the password column as a regular varchar and then insert like this:

```
sha1($pass_string)
```

Or should I do something extra upon the creation of the table to make sure that password field is secure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a normal varchar field (40 characters) but if you want to set it more secure you should use salt.

http://highedwebtech.com/2008/04/25/season-your-passwords-with-some-salt/

Update :

**WARNING : Hash password without salt is REALLY WEAK ! You should never use it  !!**

Password salting is the good way for doing it :
[password salting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_salting)

as adviced by pst :

- using SHA-1 and salt is the more naive but quite well secure approach.
- using [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) :

it's the more secure approach :) because it use speed in order to make it more secure, bfish is a hash function built around the encryption method blowfish. (Seems than twofish exists too and should be the "modern" version of blowfish).

- using [HMAC-SHA1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) :

It's a version using a chain of SHA-1 so it's a intermediate solution, but allowing to set speed to your needs. In fact speed make weaker your security.

Comment: Also should use a different ("more computationally expensive") function such as `bcrypt` and/or use an HMAC-hash.

Comment: Yes, definitely salt your hashes. Also, if you use a different salt for each user, you help prevent Rainbow Table attacks: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table

Comment: @pst : could you give more details ? :)

Comment: @ykatchou http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561174/sha512-vs-blowfish-and-bcrypt (bottom of accepted answer) and http://www.binarylogic.com/2008/11/22/storing-nuclear-launch-codes-in-your-app-enter-bcrypt-for-authlogic/ -- it isn't that SHA isn't a secure hash, it's just that a naive single call is *just too fast*. Since `bcrypt` was already designed for this, I see no need to "roll another" (unless you're designing a new algorithm/approach).

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the AES_ENCRYPT() function built into mysql for greater security.
[Link here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-decrypt)

There is also a good how-to here explaining further: [link](http://www.johnboy.com/blog/how-to-use-mysqls-aes_encrypt-and-aes_decrypt-to-store-passwords-in-a-database)

Answer (score 2):

[The manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha1) contains a good explanation of what type of column to use.

Answer (score 0):

Most people save the hash as you have suggested. It's safe enough and simple, making it a good choice.

Note that all hashes can be cracked eventually, so any hash is better than none and SHA is strong enough.

Comment: This is worse than that -- without a salt a trivial rainbow table attack will easily break it. Also, a single SHA is less-than-ideal for passwords because *it can be computed extremely quickly*. (`bcrypt` and HMAC can help address that.)

Comment: is hmac usefull for data smaller than one block ?

Comment: @ykatchou Oops, the comment is slightly incorrect. [HMAC-SHA1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) isn't designed to "help" with the speed, but what it can do is add another level of hardening with a server-secret key.

Comment: @pst : thanks to you, i discover bcrypt :) which help with the speed !