# How to output passwords in text format stored in mysql table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, passwords

I created a "users" table in a MySQL database using phpmyadmin in "ApacheFriends XAMPP (Basispaket) version 1.7.4" but when I want to see the data in table fields, other fields are showing text stored in them but Password field only showing word "Password".
How can I see the passwords stored in Password field in text form?

Image is attached here.
[image: Password field not showing password in text form]

Comment: We are not supposed to be able to see these passwords, ever. They should be properly hashed and salted, and never present in the database in clear text. That would be a breach of data security. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522373/how-to-create-tables-with-password-fields-in-mysql

Comment: let us know your query that you have written to retrieve data

Comment: is it mean that even database administrator cannot see the passwords stored in the database table in mysql ???

Comment: mysql_connect ("localhost","root","") or die ("Problem with connection...");

mysql_select_db ("testsite");

$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM users");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)) {
 echo $row ['Name']." ".$row['Email']." ".$row['Password'];
 echo "<br />";
}

mysql_close();

Comment: Means no way to see saved passwords in my mysql database ?????