# Using crypt PHP function with Blowfish hashing algorithm, is it Symmetric crypting or not?

Tags: php, blowfish, encryption-symmetric, crypt

as I can read from the net: Blowfish algorithm is symmetric.
And from PHP.net  crypt function is one way crypting.Crypt func also allows Blowfish as hashing algorithm.

So if I'm correct when I associate symmetric crypting with two way crypting procedure.
I see a contraddiction.

Definitely, using crypt() + Blowfish will give someone the chance to decrypt the string, 
if ever he will know the secret salt?
(I actually think not since as I can see from the crypted string the crypting salt is included)

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cipher algorithm like blowfish can be used as part of a hashing algorithm. Blowfish is just a "building block" and can be used for different purposes. It can be implemented as an encryption/decryption tool, or as the cryptographic primitive of a hash algorithm. This does not mean that you are suddenly able to reverse a hashing algorithm.

The plain fact that the output of the hashing algorithm is always a constant length is a giveaway that it cannot be reversed. You cannot encrypt an infinite number of potential input values in a reversible way into a fixed length output. The algorithm is by necessity *lossy*.

As a simple illustration, blowfish can be used like this to *encrypt* data (which can subsequently be *decrypted*):

```
ABCD EFGH IJKL MNOP ...
  |    |    |    |
  v    v    v    v
NPCQ JQ0C  MPZW LKAQ
```

Each *block* of the input is turned into cipher text individually by blowfish. That is why blowfish is called a *block cipher* (as opposed to a *stream cipher* which would process the input as a stream, not as a set of blocks of fixed length). The result of this operation are a bunch of blocks which can be reversed. The output is of the same length as the input (plus padding to fill a block where necessary).

A hash function using blowfish works like this:

```
ABCD EFGH        IJKL        MNOP ...
  |    |           |           |
  v    v           v           v
NPCQ JQ0C        MPZW        LKAQ
  |    |           |           |
  +----+--> PMQZ --+--> OLMQ --+--> UALG ...
```

The output of each block is run through a *compression function* which combines two blocks into one. The output of the first two blocks are combined (into `PMQZ`), then this value is combined with the output of the third block (into `OLMQ`) and so on. The output of the last compression is the result of the hash.

As you see, blowfish is used internally as a cryptographic cipher, but its output is combined with a lossy compression function which makes it impossible to reverse the output.

Answer (score 1):

encrypted things are decryptable, if it isn't decryptable it's called hashing, hashing is one-way.

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking about it the wrong way; the salt and password together is used as the key, while there is a magic string that's the data (the password is not the data). Without the key, no decryption. This is then iterated over (which is what bcrypt does).

See [sha512 vs blowfish vs bcrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561174/sha512-vs-blowfish-and-bcrypt) for a very good answer.