# Hashing multiple values - most secure method?

Tags: hash, salt

```
hash(value1 & value2 & salt)
hash(hash(value1 & value2) & salt)
hash(hash(value1 & value2) & hash(salt))
hash(hash(value1 & salt) & hash(value2 & salt))
hash(hash(value1 & salt1) & hash(value2 & salt2))
hash(value1 & salt1 &value2 & salt2)
hash(value1 & salt1) and hash(value2 & salt2)  '2 separate hashes for each input
```

In an application where 2 'passwords' are needed to access a specific function (for whatever reason you want) and the salt(s) are large random strings.  What would be the best way of getting a final hash to store? (not necessarily 1 of the above)

Is it 'better' to have the outside/final hash algorithm different to the inner ones?

Side question: is a salt mainly for making short, crappy user pw's more secure from brute force attacks? So if the pw was large (say the ByteArray of an image file) would a salt add any real purpose?  Thanks.

Comment: What does `&` mean in this context? Is it concatenation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `&` means concatenation, the safest is:

```
hash(value1 & delim & value2 & delim & salt)
```

...where `delim` is a delimiter that cannot appear in any of the other strings. It doesn't matter which order value1, value2 and salt appear in.

The delimeter prevents aliasing, e.g., `(value1, value2) = ('fail', 'stone')` vs `(value1, value2) = ('fails', 'tone')`.

Comment: Thanks. I read this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348109/is-double-hashing-a-password-less-secure-than-just-hashing-it-once