# mechanism for hashing passwords

Tags: asp.net, security, hash, passwords

I have a .net application that stores hashed passwords in a sql server database.

The passwords are hashed using a salt that gets stored in the database with the hashed passwords.

As an extra layer of security, I hash the hashed password with another sitewide secret key that is not stored on the database server for security reasons. As the system is load balanced, where should I store the sitewide secret key? Store a copy of it in the config of each of my .net applications (same value on all servers).

Second question is, what is the recommended hashing mechanism for storing passwords?

Comment: What hash algorithm do you use? It is unlikely that hashing again will significantly improve security; consult [Is double-hashing a password less secure...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348109/).

Comment: Does it matter to much where you store the site specific salt as long as they are not visible (and can never be) visible on the internet?  If a server breaks into your DB and your web server they can probably get at your site specific salt easily.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use bcrypt storing passwords.  The .NET implementation of it is [BCrypt.NET](http://bcrypt.codeplex.com/) as it doesn't come in the .NET framework at this point.  You do not want to use a general purpose hash function like MD5.  Another common algorithm is [PBKDF2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163913.aspx), but I have not personally used it in .NET.