# Combine CRC32(), MD5() && SHA256 to make a Salt Combination is too much ?

Tags: php, md5, salt, sha256, hash

The problem maybe that it would overcharge the server Memory while Creating Hashes and maybe twice while loading it.

So did you think is better to make a function that specializes in this or just use the default  SHA256 instead?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348109/is-double-hashing-a-password-less-secure-than-just-hashing-it-once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the context here is hashing passwords. Why reimplement what already exists? If you have PHP 5.5, you can take advantage of the new [password hashing library](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), which drastically simplifies the whole process.

If you're running an older version of PHP, I'd use a tried and tested framework, such as [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/).

Comment: There's a answer that let me thinking so much so i wont try to re-invent the wheel! and i would choose one of the default ones even if it means to update it every month or once 2 weeks.