# Does reapplyingsha1() to passwords over and over aagain help at all?

Tags: php, password-storage

Since the PHP sha1() can be broken quite easily by comparing against a long list of hashes - would this be any better (basically - applying sha1() over and over again to try and make brute forcing impractical by slowing the hashing process down):

```
<?php
    $iterations = 100000;
    $pass       = 'hyugf67rf76dt564d5r76';
    $salt       = '6t6755636459679guytfugiuhbguiygfytcdtresr5tdt5yfuybiugbuyfr56d45esertdcftyuuguy';
    $hash       = '';

    for ($i=0; $i<$iterations;$i++) {
        $hash = sha1($hash . $pass . $salt);
    }

    echo $salt . $hash;
?>
```

Comment: The best way to make passwords more secure is by salting, and by using a better hashing algorithm than sha1

Comment: Stop "dicking around" and use the password hashing functions sprovided by php http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php

Comment: The simple answer is "NO" - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348109/is-double-hashing-a-password-less-secure-than-just-hashing-it-once - because simply repeating sha1() several times doesn't preserve entropy but reduces it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of applying the `sha1` over again and again , why not implement [`crypt()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) once with a stronger - salt ?

If you have PHP 5.5 +, you could simply go for [`password_hash()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

A userland implementation of password_hash() is also available [here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

**HINT :** You could combine the examples #4 and #3 of the `password_hash()`documentation link above to creater a stronger hash.

---

or use [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)

> The preferred **(most secure) hashing method supported by phpass is the
>   OpenBSD-style Blowfish-based bcrypt, also supported with our public
>   domain crypt_blowfish package (for C applications), and known in PHP
>   as CRYPT_BLOWFISH,** with a fallback to BSDI-style extended DES-based
>   hashes, known in PHP as CRYPT_EXT_DES, and a last resort fallback to
>   MD5-based salted and variable iteration count password hashes
>   implemented in phpass itself (also referred to as portable hashes).

Comment: Or the userland implementation of password_hash() if you're using an earlier version of PHP

Comment: @Downvoter , Please point out the issues , so the answer can be rectified.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to approach the problem, is by using a hashing algorithm that has this cost-intensity built-in, instead of using a custom function. If the resulting hash is not truly random, this could be a security problem.

That doesn't answer your question though, so I'll try to do that now.

**Cost-intensity**

If applied correctly, algorithms that are more cost-intensive make it more cost-intensive for an attacker to crack all passwords from a database. If applied incorrectly though, most of this cost-intensity can be bypassed. This is why I recommend using an algorithm that is designed to be cost-intensive, rather than trying to create something yourself.

**Salts**

A database-wide salt only protects you from rainbow tables without a salt. When an attacker obtains your database with passwords, and knows the salt, they can make their own rainbow table with your salt, and crack every password in the database with this rainbow table. Users with the same password have the same hash in the database.

A per-account salt (a salt that is different for each account), an attacker has to crack each password individually. Users with the same password have a different hash in the database. Cracking passwords is much more costly now.

**Iteration**

What you should be wary of when reapplying, is that the attacker should not be able to create a lookup table for part of this iteration. In other words: The iteration should contain something that is different for every user, and even better, different for every password tried for an user. Since you re-use the password in the algorithm, this should be no problem.*

A little change to the algorithm could however allow an attacker to bypass most of the iteration. In the following code, the attacker could create a lookup table that translates a hash to a hash with sha1 applied 99.999. In fact, such a table can be created by applying it just once on every hash, then using that lookup table multiple times. Instead of needing to apply sha1 100.000 times for every password, this now has been reduced to creating a lookup table, applying sha1 exactly once for every password, and looking up a hash in a lookup table once for every password. Even with a per-user salt, this would make no difference to the lookup table.

If you would use a per-user salt and change the line with `//here` to `sha1($hash . $salt)`, the attacker has to create such a table for every unique salt in the database. This is slightly more work, but still much less than the work an attacker has to do when he has to calculate every hash for every password they try out.

```
<?php
    #Bad code below
    $iterations = 100000;
    $pass       = 'hyugf67rf76dt564d5r76';
    $salt       = '6t6755636459679guytfugiuhbguiygfytcdtresr5tdt5yfuybiugbuyfr56d45esertdcftyuuguy';
    $hash       = sha1($hash . $pass . $salt);

    for ($i=0; $i<$iterations;$i++) {
        $hash = sha1($hash); //Here
    }

    echo $salt . $hash;
?>
```

---

* I am by no means a security expert. I am a student with some knowledge about algorithms, and some knowledge about security, but the fact I don't see a problem doesn't mean there isn't a problem.

Comment: Security hurts my head

Comment: @Richard - precisely why the recommended method of hashing passwords for PHP is password_hash(), which uses best principles and means that you don't need to hurt your head

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have PHP 5.5 and am also too busy/lazy to upgrade. :-/