# Using another algorithm on top of an hashing one

Tags: algorithm, security, web, hash, password-encryption

For my Web class project I was told to make a website with login/logout functionality and one of the things my professors demanded was using hashing algorithms to encrypt the users password.

Is it smart to do 1 or more different algorithms to convert my data(in this case a string) before doing the hashing algorithm(ex: MD5, SHA-1,etc)?

Comment: I'm not sure it's the sort of thing you had in mind, but it's certainly smart to salt the data first, to give just one obvious example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No it's not.**

Short answer, it won't increase security, and will probably only increase the risk of collisions.

---

Make sure you use an algorithm designed to hash password like [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) or [BCrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt). Hashing algorithm like `MD5` and `SHA-1` were created to be efficient, not secure and therefore should never be used to hash password.

Also, use a salt to hash to password to prevent [preimage attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack).

Comment: I was generally talking. If I use a salt and an algorithm designed for my password is it safer if I use a self-made encryption algorithm before all that process?

Comment: No. Modern cryptographic hash function are already very good. At best, adding your algorithm won't increase security in any way. But there is a good chance doing so will weaken it.

Comment: Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348109/is-double-hashing-a-password-less-secure-than-just-hashing-it-once?rq=1) for more details