# approaches to encrypt password in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, encryption, passwords

Hai guys,

Thus far i am using the following statements for encrypting a password variable in sql server 2005

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SecureSymmetricKey1
DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = N'StrongPassword';

 DECLARE @encrypted_str VARBINARY(MAX)
select @encrypted_str=EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('SecureSymmetricKey1'),@Password)
```

Is this a good practice or any other approach for doing this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find this post on [preferred-method-of-storing-passwords-in-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615704/preferred-method-of-storing-passwords-in-database) in Stackoverflow useful as well

Answer (score 2):

If you mean your application user password it would be much easier (and probably good enough) to just [hash and salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) the user password.

There are a few reasons:

- Hashing password is common practice/standard.
- Password should not be recoverable from database (even with access to database it's hard to recover the password).
- Database is not a calculator -- it's storing engine (advanced engine, but for storing data, not calculating them).

In SQL Server 2005 there is a function [HashBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx) is available. Don't forget to [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) password before hash.

Exemplary code using `HashBytes` could look like this:

```
DECLARE 
    @password nvarchar(100),
    @salt AS nvarchar(100)

SET @salt = 'various random characters i.e. #_$a1b'
SET @password = 'my password'

SELECT HashBytes('SHA1', @salt + @password)
```

However, probably, it's much easier to make hash directly in application and only save hashed password to database.

Comment: @gierlik any example of using hash in sql server 2005

Comment: Don't use SHA1, it's a weak hash consider dead (http://valerieaurora.org/hash.html) use SHA-2 or up.

Comment: HashBytes() provides just MD2, MD4, MD5 and SHA-1. One more reason to generate hash inside application.