# How to store password on gae properly when someone registers?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, passwords, google-cloud-datastore

For example:

```
username:zjm1126
password:11
```

I store the password to the datastore on gae. When I see the data view at `/_ah/admin`, I can see the password of all people that have registered.

Is it safe to do so? If not, how to store it properly?

And the `check_password` method is:

```
user=MyUser.get_by_key_name(self.request.get('username'))
if user.password == self.request.get('password'):
    session['user.key']=str(user.key())
else:
    raise Exception('error 404')
```

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should *never* store a password in plain text.

Use a ir-reversable data hashing algorithm, like `sha` or `md5`

Here is how you can create a hash in python:

```
from hashlib import sha256
from random import random
random_key = random()
sha256('%s%s%s'%('YOUR SECRET KEY',random_key,password))
```

You should also store the random key and hash the user supplied password similarly.

Comment: md5 should not be recommended.

Comment: md5 is okay for small databases, I doubt you will have enough users to clash

Comment: @DanDan Why do you say that MD5 is okay but only for small databases? Database size can't be a reason to use a cryptographic algorithm or another.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing app-engine specific or new about this question that hasn't been answered 10 times before on SO.  Search Stack Overflow for
[store password](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=store+password) and read the first 5 questions.  That should give you a good foundation in the subject.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous posts on stackoverflow about how to use various algorithms to product the integrity of passwords. Algorithms you should look into are SHA-256/SHA-512 in conjunction with a long randomly generated salt (which would also be stored in the database) or bcrypt. I won't go into the discussion of why one is better than the other here because that discussion is already taking place in other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615704/preferred-method-of-storing-passwords-in-database).