# NodeJS - Passport password appears as plain text in DB

Tags: node.js, passport.js

Probably I am missing something here.

Got an Express server with MongoDB and i'm using passport to authenticate.
I'm using one of the standard code example to signup and it seems ok, but I can see the password I type in the password field (plain text) in my DB.
I expected it to be encrypted...

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Mongodb does not treat passwords any different from other text. You would have to handle encryption yourself. You can look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951563/storing-passwords-with-node-js-and-mongodb). Answers attempt to solve a similar issue. And storing passwords is not a good idea. Better store their salted hash.

Comment: Basically the mongodb merely provides storage. You have to use bcrypt or other library to handle the security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to hash the password yourself. Here is how to do it using brcypt:

```
function hashPassword (password) {
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync());
}
```

So before you save your user to the DB simply invoke that function like so:

```
 user.password = hashPassword(thepassword);
```