# Password Encryption with ColdFusion and MySQL

Tags: mysql, encryption, coldfusion, passwords

I am looking for some help/recommendations on the best way to encrypt/decrypt passwords in my ColdFusion/MySQL app. Should I use MD5, SHA, BCrypt? Should I do the encryption directly in MySQL or use ColdFusion to handle it?

Just looking for some help with this and some examples to get me going.

Security is pretty important with this app because we will be storing sensitive information.

Any help would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By using a SALT with your encryption, you'll improve security even more. Also have a look at this question about [storing passwords in database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615704/preferred-method-of-storing-passwords-in-database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SHA-256 or higher with salt, or BCrypt.

I'd do it in CF layer 'cause the code will be source controlled.

http://blog.mxunit.org/2011/02/hashing-passwords-with-bcrypt-in.html

http://www.12robots.com/index.cfm/2008/5/21/Salting-Passwords-Security-Series-4.3

Answer (score 1):

If you want the passwords to be secure definately don't use MD5 as it can be cracked. Wouldn't recommend SHA-1 either.

It's safer to use at least SHA-256, for example like this in CF:

```
variables.hashedPassword = Hash(variables.Password,"SHA-256");
```

As for choosing where to do the encryption - it depends on what exactly do you want to use it for, number of password to be encrypted in one go, etc. If it's just one time only it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

I use ColdFusion to do all my encryption/decryption.  ColdFusion makes it really easy.  I usually use Blowfish encryption and have ColdFusion generate the key value. Then set it as a static value in the Application.cfm file.

Here is more info: [Enrypt()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_e-g_01.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's great that you're concerned with strong hashing for your passwords.  I would recommend the use of the [scrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt) libary. Colin Percival, who invented it for use with tarsnap, has written a great comparison of scrypt, available on the tarsnap website (sorry, can't post more than two links due to rep < 10) to other well-known and strong PBKDFs like bcrypt and PBKDF2 that answers the question of why scrypt may be advantageous in use over other PBKDFs from a technical perspective.

I am generally cautious about jumping on the bandwagon for the use of crypto that hasn't been around a while and been well-vetted by the crypto community.  Thus, I had a bit of reservation about using scrypt, since it is still rather "new" in that regard.  I consulted security expert [Steve Gibson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Gibson_%28computer_programmer%29) regarding the question via Twitter, and this was his reply:

> @SGgrc Any thoughts on use of bcrypt vs scrypt for PBKD for a web aplication? *[sic]*
>
> @geekmuse SCrypt more strongly resists hardware acceleration than
>   BCrypt. So I'd say, if your applicaton CAN use it, do use it. :)
>
> @SGgrc Will do -- and thanks for the info!  My only hesitation was
>   seemingly less thoroughly vetted by the crypto community.
>
> @geekmuse Understood, and in crypto, being conservative is never
>   wrong. But currently, SCrypt is the best memory-hard solution
>   available.

Additionally, ColdFusion's built-in crypto (Enterprise edition, at least) uses RSA BeSafe's library, which is now strongly suspected of being compromised due to the NSA (depending on which PRNG one uses, but still...), so you're doing the right thing by looking at some of the more recently published algorithms.

There is a Java-based scrypt implementation available on Github (github.com/wg/scrypt), which should be quite amenable to use in your ColdFusion application.

Lastly, while I know your question specifically mentions strong crypto for user passwords, depending on the sensitivity of the data you're storing, you might also want to seriously consider encrypting the sensitive data while it's at rest in the database as well.  That way, if your data is ever compromised, you can rest a bit easier knowing it was encrypted at rest (unless your key is compromised as well, but you would want to store that in a different location than your actual database that your application has access to).