# Check if encrypted password exists in DB

Tags: python, mongodb, bcrypt

I have an encrypted password with bcrypt. I want to check if the user input password exists in the DB.I am using mongoDB. How do I need to check that ? I need to encrypt the input password with the original salt and check if the pattern exists in the DB? if so how do I retrieve the salt? And If the salt is so easy to be retrieved what is the point of it from the outset?

Comment: On a point of clarity, bcrypt is not an encryption algorithm, it is a one way hashing algorithm. Changing the word "encrypted" to "hashed" would be more accurate.

Comment: What is the difference? Can you answer my question also please?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55904/2282634

Comment: still dont understand how to check if the password exists in the DB if the salt always changes and hashing the input will give me different result because of the salt

Answer (score 0):

If you see a string in the database of the form:

```
$2a$12$tEKPayfQg.iLSLU5OqIeZOjQWe0r6ju7Bh8/WNa7u0sHNg214dptm
```

That is bcrypt.